# HTML5 graphs in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, graph

I'm new to html5 and trying to display an array of code in a graph. It works for a line graph but for some reason unknown to me not for an exponential one. this my code.

My question is, is there a fault in the code that would break the graph?(i'm sure there's a metric ton of mistakes in the code).

I also got a lot of [my code here](http://www.worldwidewhat.net/2011/06/draw-a-line-graph-using-html5-canvas/).

thanks in advance for any help I receive.

```html
<canvas id="graph5" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```

```js
function generateTestData5() // generates the array 
{
    var data = [];
    for(var i=0; i<300; i++){
        var sensfi = ((document.getElementById("f5").value)*(document.getElementById("xPos5").value)*(document.getElementById("f5").value))/((i*i*document.getElementById("sDI5").value)/(document.getElementById("rI5").value));
        data[i] = sensfi;
    }
    return data;
}

var graph;
var xPadding = 40;
var yPadding = 40;

function getMaxY5() {
    var data = generateTestData5();
    var max = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
        if(data[i] > max) {
            max = data[i];
        }
    }

    max += 10 - max % 10;
    return max;
}

function getXPixel5(val) {
    var data = generateTestData5();
    return ((graph.width() - 20) / data.length) * val + (20 * 1.5);
}

function getYPixel5(val) {
    var data = generateTestData5();
    return graph.height() - (((graph.height() - 20) / getMaxY5()) * val) - 20;
}

function draw5(){
    var data = generateTestData5();
    graph = $('#graph5');
    var c = graph[0].getContext('2d');

    c.lineWidth = 2;
    c.strokeStyle = '#333';
    c.font = 'italic 8pt sans-serif';
    c.textAlign = "center";

    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(xPadding, 0);
    c.lineTo(xPadding, graph.height() - yPadding);
    c.lineTo(graph.width(), graph.height() - yPadding);
    c.stroke();

    var x = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length + 1; i ++) {

        if(x==30) {
            c.fillText(i, getXPixel5(i), graph.height() - yPadding + 20);
            x=0;}
        else {
            x++;
        }
    }


    c.textAlign = "right";
    c.textBaseline = "middle";

    for(var i = 0; i < getMaxY5(); i += getMaxY5()/10) {
        c.fillText(i, xPadding-10, getYPixel5(i));
    }
    c.strokeStyle = '#f00';
    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(getXPixel5(0)+10, getYPixel5(data[0])-20);

    for(var i = 1; i < data.length + 1; i ++) {
        c.lineTo(getXPixel5(i)+10, getYPixel5(data[i])-20);
    }
    c.stroke();
    //c.clearRect(0,0,graph.width(),graph.height());     
}
```

Comment: Without knowing the value of f5, xPos5, sDI5 and rI5, we can't generate any test data.

Comment: My apologies,  the values are : f5 = 8, xpos5 = 100, sDI5 = 6.4 and rI5 = 1280.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change width() and height() to width and height a few times (they are simple properties), start the test data at 1 because otherwise the first value is always +infinity", and store data and max instead of generating them multiple times, but now it seems to work.

```js
var data; /* KEEP DATA AS A GLOBAL VARIABLE INSTEAD OF GENERATING IT AGAIN EACH TIME */
var graph;
var xPadding = 40;
var yPadding = 40;

function generateTestData5() // generates the array 
{
    var data = [];
    for(var i=1; i<=300; i++){
        var sensfi = ((document.getElementById("f5").value)*(document.getElementById("xPos5").value)*(document.getElementById("f5").value))/((i*i*document.getElementById("sDI5").value)/(document.getElementById("rI5").value));
        data[i-1] = sensfi;
    }
    return data;
}

function getMaxY5() {
    var max = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i ++) {
        if(data[i] > max) {
            max = data[i];
        }
    }

    max += 10 - max % 10;
    return max;
}

function getXPixel5(val) {
    return ((graph.width - 20) / data.length) * val + (20 * 1.5);
}

function getYPixel5(val) {
    return graph.height - (((graph.height - 20) / getMaxY5()) * val) - 20;
}

function draw5(){
    data = generateTestData5(); /* USE THE GLOBAL VARIABLE */
    var max = getMaxY5(); /* STORE MAX INSTEAD OF CHECKING IT MULTIPLE TIMES */
    graph = document.getElementById("graph5");
    var c = graph.getContext('2d');

    c.lineWidth = 2;
    c.strokeStyle = '#333';
    c.font = 'italic 8pt sans-serif';
    c.textAlign = "center";

    c.beginPath();
    c.moveTo(xPadding, 0);
    c.lineTo(xPadding, graph.height - yPadding);
    c.lineTo(graph.width, graph.height - yPadding);
    c.stroke();

    var x = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length + 1; i ++) {

        if(x==30) {
            c.fillText(i, getXPixel5(i), graph.height - yPadding + 20);
            x=0;}
        else {
            x++;
        }
    }

    c.textAlign = "right";
    c.textBaseline = "middle";

    for(var i = 0; i < max; i += max/10) {
        c.fillText(i, xPadding-10, getYPixel5(i));
    }
    c.strokeStyle = '#f00';
    c.beginPath();

    c.moveTo(getXPixel5(0)+10, getYPixel5(data[0])-20);

    for(var i = 1; i < data.length + 1; i ++) {
        c.lineTo(getXPixel5(i)+10, getYPixel5(data[i])-20);
    }
    c.stroke();
    //c.clearRect(0,0,graph.width,graph.height);     
}

draw5();
```

```html
<form>
<input name="f5" id="f5" value=8>
<input name="xpos5" id="xPos5" value=100>
<input name="sDI5" id="sDI5" value=6.4>
<input name="rI5" id="rI5" value=1280>
</form>
<canvas id="graph5" width="400" height="300"></canvas>
```